# Custom delete method doesn't call in custom datasource

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using a custom datasource to consume webservice.
Create, Read and Update work well but Delete doesn't works.

Here is my code calling the delete method in my controller.

```
    public function delete($id){

        $this->autoRender = false;
        debug($this->Article->delete($id));
}
```

And here the code in my datasource

```
public function delete(Model $Model, $id = null) {
    echo "Display a message if this method is called";
    $json = $this->Http->post(CakeSession::read('Site.url') . '/webservice/delete/', array(
        'id' => $id,
        'apiKey' => $this->config['apiKey'],
        'model' => $Model->name
        ));

$res = json_decode($json, true);

if (is_null($res)) {
    $error = json_last_error();
    throw new CakeException($error);
}
return true;
}
```

But when I want to delete an item, the `debug();` display `false`.
I have no other displays.
I don't understand why my delete method isn't called correctly.
Is there something wrong in my code ?

Thanks

Comment: The datasource code is taken from the manual, it should be working fine. Can you show us the output of `debug($res)`?

Comment: I digg in the core class and I found why my delete() isn't called. In fact before the delete method triggered the _findCount() on the Model.php is called. And there is a `if (!method_exists($db, 'calculate') || !method_exists($db, 'expression')){return false;}`.
In my datasource class I only have the method calculate() and not the expression(). So I implement the function, and now it's working

Answer (score 0):

Let's check: you're only passing a parameter to your method:

```
$this->Article->delete($id)
```

According to the method that you created, the first parameter, which is required, is the `Model`. The second is `$id`:

```
public function delete(Model $Model, $id = null)
```

During the method you want to use both parameters. Here:

```
'id' => $id
```

And here:

```
'model' => $Model->name
```

Based on this, you need to review how this method will be called. BTW, if you want override `delete()` method, according the **[book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html)**, you need something like this: `delete(int $id = null, boolean $cascade = true)`.

Comment: My datasource class extend the class `DataSource`, so `delete()` overriding depend on this `delete()` I think : http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-DataSource.html#_delete